# Start session when page is loaded in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, session

I want to create a session at the first visit on a page. I can do it, when I'm logged in. So the session get's created when I log in. When i log out, then a new session get's created.

I added to **functions.php** following code:

```
/**
* Start Session
*/
function start_session() {
   if(session_id) {
       session_start();
   }
}
add_action('init', 'start_session');

/**
* End Session 
*/
function end_session() {
session_destroy ();
}
add_action('wp_logout','end_session');
add_action('wp_login','end_session');
```

Comment: what is the end game ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I wanna make an website, where you can vote for stuff. Therefore you don't need to be logged in. I achieved, that when you logged in and you leave the page and come back, that your progress is saved in sessions. But now I dont have a session, when I'm not logged in.